# Where block template for email is located

Tags: template, email, magento-1.3

I found in an old Magento 1.3 installation following code in an email template:

```
{{block type="symmetrics_impressum/impressum" value="emailfooter"}}
```

It works and this snippet implement my imprint in system-emails. But I have no idea, where *emailfooter* is located. I need this for transfer in a new system. Can anybody explain, how *type* and *value* works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here **type** is required, others attributes are optional. In your case **symmetrics_impressum** block name which is declared in config.xml and impressum is the actual class.

**symmetrics_impressum** reffers to app/code/[local/community]/VendorName/ModuleName/Block.

Your block class is:

> app/code/[local/community]/VendorName/ModuleName/Block/Impressum.php

Inside block and related phtml file, you can access value by getValue that you declared as an attribute.